# lateinit property instance has not been initialized, while making an app

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, kotlin-lateinit

I'm a new developer(If I can call myself one) making an alarm app. I think I made other parts of the app but however hard I try, I can't find out how to fix the error. To access **instance** in **AlarmManager.kt**, I can't help but make **instance** companion object. But I guess that makes the problem.... Please could anyone tell me how can I fix this error? Thanks in advance!

**kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property instance has not been initialized**

↓ SampleApplication.kt

```
class SampleApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: SampleApplication private set
    }
}
```

↓AlarmManager.kt

```
object AlarmManager {
    var mService: MusicService? = null
    lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    lateinit var mView: View
    lateinit var mTimer: Timer
    val tag1 = "alarm1"
    val tag2 = "alarm2"
    private val windowManager: WindowManager by lazy {
        SampleApplication.instance.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    }
```

Comment: when and where you are using this `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Can you check https://github.com/illizien/Study-Aider please? It's too long to when and where it's being used!

Comment: Have you register SampleApplication in AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to register `SampleApplication` in AndroidManifest file. Then only it will executed as an application class

```
<application
    android:name=".SampleApplication">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You saved me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there's 'accept'. I clicked on that V sign in the left(I thought up vote is 'accept')

Comment: Man such a silly mistake I was doing. Thanks. I thought something new came up in compose UI, and I resumed android after 3 years